# Trouble finding the derivative of an expression

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, derivatives

I could use your help. I've spent over 20 minutes on this problem and my inability to solve it has my questioning my calculus skills. If someone could show me where I messed up and walk me through the rest of the steps that would be great, for some reason my answer doesn't match the book.

I am supposed to find the derivative of $y = (2x-5)^4(8x^2-5)^{-3}$, here are my steps, first using the product rule:

$$4(2x-5)^3[2](8x^2-5)^{-3} + (2x-5)^4[-3(8x^2-5)^{-4}(16x)]$$

$$8(2x-5)^3(8x^2-5)^{-3} + (2x-5)^4[-48x(8x^2-5)^{-4}]$$

Now my next intuition would be to factor out a $(2x-5)$ from both parts but that seems to lead me down the wrong road. Could somebody help me out?

Comment: You are missing the exponent on $(8x^2-5)$ in the first term and the exponent on $(2x-5)$ in the second term.

Comment: Whoops, fixed now.

Comment: What answer do you get? Your steps up to now, and factoring out powers of $(2x-5)$ and $(8x^2-5)$ would give you the answer.

Comment: I get: $(8x-5)^{-3}[(2x-5)^3(8-48(2x-5)(8x^2-5)^{-1}]$

Comment: Continue on. Maybe take the factor $(8x-5)^{-4}$ instead.

Comment: You're missing the square in $(8x^2-5)$. And yes you should try to factor things out so that what is left will be a polynomial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with where you left off, factoring gives

$8(2x-5)^3(8x^2-5)^{-3} + (2x-5)^4[-48x(8x^2-5)^{-4}]
=8(2x-5)^3(8x^2-5)^{-4}[(8x^2-5)-6x(2x-5)]=8(2x-5)^3(8x^2-5)^{-4}[-4x^2+30x-5]=\displaystyle
\frac{8(2x-5)^3[-4x^2+30x-5]}{(8x^2-5)^4}.$

---

If we use the Quotient Rule instead, we get

$\displaystyle\frac{(8x^2-5)^3\cdot4(2x-5)^3\cdot2-(2x-5)^4\cdot3(8x^2-5)^2\cdot16x}{(8x^2-5)^6}=\frac{8(2x-5)^3(8x^2-5)^2[8x^2-5-6x(2x-5)]}{(8x^2-5)^6}=\frac{8(2x-5)^3[-4x^2+30x-5]}{(8x^2-5)^4}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let me provide a small trick which is very convenient when you have expressions such as $$F(x)=A(x)^a \times B(x)^b$$ It is logarithmic differentiation. So, start writing $$\log\Big(F(x)\Big)=a\log\Big(A(x)\Big)+b \log\Big(B(x)\Big)$$ and write the derivatives $$\frac{F'(x)}{F(x)}=a\frac{A'(x)}{A(x)}+b\frac{B'(x)}{B(x)}$$ Now, multiply both sides by $F(x)$ and get $$F'(x)=A(x)^{a-1} B(x)^{b-1} \Big(a B(x) A'(x)+b A(x) B'(x)\Big)$$

Comment: Although this gets the correct answer, the justification you give here is actually incorrect! It might not be easy to fix the issue of $A$ or $B$ being zero on some inputs.

Comment: @user21820. You are correct, for sure. But, if I take the logarithm of $something$, I assume that $something \neq 0$

Comment: I'm saying that your final conclusion about the derivative of $F$ is correct for any differentiable $A,B$ but the derivation is wrong, and fails when $A$ or $B$ is zero at some points, even though the formula still holds at those points. Also, for this method to work for complex functions we need to use the multi-valued $\ln$, though I still don't see a way to handle the problem of zeros. I point this out because many people never think about these issues when they take logarithms. So while it can be used as a mnemonic, I would simply use the product rule and induction for an actual proof.

Answer (score 1):

$$8(2x-5)^3(8x^2-5)^{-3} + (2x-5)^4[-48x(8x^2-5)^{-4}]$$

When I am factoring a complex expression like this, I keep two rules in mind that make things easier for me:

1. Factor out common factors with the **smallest** exponent. This makes factoring with negative exponents much easier because you *always* factor out the smallest one (i.e. the most negative).
2. Factoring is essentially division. This means that you **subtract** exponents. So when factoring $A^{-4}$ from $A^{-3}$, you get $A^{-3--4}=A$.